# How to make smooth scrolling in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have made a simple Parallax Website [link](https://parallax-ia.netlify.app/) and when I croll with my mouse, it's just way to rough. On the other hand, when you visit [this website](https://cuberto.com/projects/ulesson/), you will notice such a smooth scrolling.

How can I achieve that?

I have uploaded the [source code of my website](https://github.com/inclinedadarsh/parallax) on GitHub.

Also, I have tried adding `scroll-behaviour: smooth;` and `transition` as well.

**Thank You**

Comment: I'm not positive of this, but I deleted your image that was scrolling the other way and it smoothed the text out a lot for me.  Maybe it is just that it is doing too many calculations at once.  I would also look into removing the 50% from left from your scrolling transform.  Call it a hunch, but I think it is making the page do more work than it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `scroll-behavior: smooth;` to `body` in your CSS. I tested on my end and worked for your website.

For smoother scrolling, maybe compress the image assets a bit more. They are pretty big.

Side Note: Do know that the parallax effect can be pretty bad for SEO.

To me, it looks fine: https://jsfiddle.net/1pw8bu2v/

Another side note: You may not have smooth scrolling enabled in Chrome. Please do check `chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling` just in case to rule it out.

Comment: doesn't work :( Plus, the images are SVG so I don't think I can compress them anymore

Comment: Let me do some tests quickly

Comment: Maybe this isn't the issue, but not all browsers have smooth scrolling enabled by Default. If you use Chrome, please try chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling

Comment: yes, it does make a difference. Now can you please tell me how can I make this work for other people who haven't enabled the setting?
Also, it is still **too** laggy, how can I fix that?

Comment: I would also try not to use SVG, maybe go for a heavily compressed JPEG. I tested this and it made heck of a lot of difference in the smoothness. Anyways, your code works quite smooth for me: https://jsfiddle.net/1pw8bu2v/

Comment: and that is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot mate

Comment: You are welcome! :)

Comment: `html {scroll-behavior: smooth;}` worked for me, on `body` it didn't work.